# When to use the high order array functions in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am reading [this](http://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/) post about Swift closures. When talking about the high order sequence functions, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, the authors says:

> One last note about higher order array functions is that they can be
> faster for large arrays than their naive equivalent because they can
> be paralellized (i.e. run on multiple cores).
>
> But I urge you to use these methods when appropriate, don’t just try to apply them to any problem.

So when should I use them? Only for large arrays? Will I get performance issues when dealing with smaller arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't get performance issues based on array size. I would say really what you should worry about is doing maps for their side-effects. Things like this are all bad practice:

```
someArray.map { println($0); return $0; }
someArray.map { $0.foo = newFoo }
```

since really all you're doing is causing side effects. If that's what you're doing, you should just use a `for-in`, like this:

```
for item in someArray { println(item) }
for item in someArray { item.foo = newFoo }
```